# Convergence of sequence of random variables and connection to convergence in topological space

Tags: real-analysis, probability

There are many types of convergence when we talk about convergent sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\cdots$, including convergence in probability, convergence in distribution, etc.

My question is, is there any connection between this type of convergence, and the typical convergence we see in metric space/topological space?

To elaborate, random variables are essentially functions from $\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. I find it difficult to define a metric or notion of "open sets" on a $\sigma$-algebra. The reason that I even started thinking about this is, topological space is the most general space on which we can define convergence that I have learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable is a measurable function on a probability space, i.e., $f:\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.

The notion(s) of [convergence for random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) are the same as in the regular functional analysis:

1. convergence in distribution = weak (point-wise) convergence of cdf
2. convergence in probability = convergence in measure
3. convergence almost surely = convergence almost everywhere
4. convergence in mean = $L^p$ convergence